# Typo3 7.6 Add custom class to Heading-Element in RTE

Tags: css, typo3, rte, typo3-7.x

I try to add a new class (`headline-red`) for headlines, especially for h5-element. I'm using the following TS setup:

```
RTE >

RTE {
    classes {
        headline-red {
            name = Heading Rot
        }
    }

    default {
        contentCSS = /typo3conf/ext/test/Resources/Public/rte.css
        useCSS = 1
        showTagFreeClasses = 1

        buttons {
            textstyle {
                tags {
                    h5 {
                        allowedClasses(
                            headline-red
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        proc {
            allowedClasses(
                headline-red
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My rte.css just contains this small testing-piece:

```
h5.headline-red {
    color: #c1002a;
}
```

But this changes nothing on the RTE editor. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your add customer header tag using typoscript.

Go To Page >> Root >> Edit (page) >> Resources and below typoscript

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout {
    addItems {
        10 = Advance Header
    }
}
```

Wrapping your header below TS.

```
lib.stdheader.10.10 >
lib.stdheader.10.10 = COA
lib.stdheader.10.10 {
   wrap = <div class="page-header"> | </div>
   20 = TEXT
   20.current = 1
   20.insertData = 1
   20.fontTag = <span class="h1" > &nbsp;|</span>
}
```

You will achieve below output.

[image]

Comment: Hmm this does not work for me. Furthermore i just want to add the class to [RTE Editor](http://i.imgur.com/ZUYnHj6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use the same solution, and it's work like a charm.

In TS Config :

```
RTE.classes.h2-bis.name = H2 alternatif 
RTE.default.contentCSS = typo3conf/ext/ps_template/res/ressources/css/rte.css
```

In Rte.css

```
h2.h2-bis{color: #ff0000;}
```

After some tests, i think the problem is just the "slash" in your css path. Try without it.

Bye